# Google Cloud Vision API - DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION: no "property" field in "pages"

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-api, gcloud, google-vision

I'm trying to extract the language from the detection response:

```
response.full_text_annotation.pages[0].property.detected_languages[0].language_code
```

but it seems that sometimes the detections are missing the `TextProperty` (`property`) field - as specified here: [Page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#Page)

Is it not always guaranteed to be in the detection?

Also, is there a way to receive only the `fullTextAnnotation` without the singular `textAnnotations` fields?

Answer (score 1):

I think is not possible to receive only the `fullTextAnnotation` without the singular `textAnnotations`, because the response structure is TextAnnotation -> Page -> Block -> Paragraph -> Word -> Symbol and if you look into the [TextAnnotation response](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#textannotation), there is no way to modify it.

Regarding the missing `TextProperty` (`property`) field, you can try to fix this by using “DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION” instead of “TEXT_DETECTION” towards TYPE. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages), The TEXT_DETECTION endpoint will auto-detect only a subset of supported languages, while the DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION endpoint will auto-detect the full set of supported languages.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. 
I am currently using `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` and am not getting the property field. It's not about detecting only a subset as not getting the field, at all.

Comment: Can you provide an example image?